# When are arrays C-contiguous and F-contiguous simultaneously?

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, contiguous

Under what conditions can arrays be C-contiguous and F-contiguous simultaneosly?

I can think of the following:

- The 1D case that is trivially C- and F-contiguous.
- Similarly, multi-dimensional arrays where all dimensions are singleton dimensions except for one.

Are there any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it.  An array is both C and Fortran contiguous (i.e. is both row major and column major) when it has at most 1 dimension longer than 1.  Basically, vectors and scalars, plus degenerate arrays with additional "unnecessary" dimensions.